# ngFor no repite elemento luego de actualizar propiedad de componente de cual dependen las repeticiones

Tags: angular

Estoy mejorando el tutorial tour_of_heroes de Angular y le agregué la propiedad "power: number" a los heroes, y quiero que con la directiva ngFor se dibujen tres elementos span al lado del nombre (como si fuesen barritas verticales).

Con la primera carga todo bien, pero después, al actualizar el valor de "power", la cantidad de barritas siempre sigue siendo o pasa a ser 1.

El código puede verse en mi repositorio: https://github.com/IgnacioMilia/Angular_Tutorial.git

El ngFor está en el componente "heroes".

```
  <span class="power"><span *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(hero.power)"></span></span>
```

El valor es inicializado en in-memory-data.service.ts y actualizado en el componente hero-detail

Comment: Las preguntas deberían ser autocontenidas. En vez de pasarnos todo tu código puedes elaborar un [mre] que nos sirva para poder ver el problema sin todo lo demás. Y como mínimo, en vez de usar tu repositorio puedes usar sitios como stackblitz que mantendrán tu mre online para que la pregunta no pierda sentido si decides borrar o mover tu repositorio

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código que has pasado he visto que el problema reside en el binding que haces del dato "power" a la hora de actualizar un hero.

La interfaz Hero espera que el dato  "power" sea de tipo number pero como podras observar en la siguiente imagen a la hora de guardarlo se guarda como string por lo cual a la hora de hacer el ngFor tan solo se encuentra un item en la variable power asi que solo se pinta una raya al lado del nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solucionar esto debes decirle el tipo de dato que va emitir al input del dato power.

ruta: src\app\hero-detail\hero-detail.component.html

```
<input id="hero-power" [(ngModel)]="hero.power" placeholder="power" type="number">
```